# Mirror modifier on a curve doesn't work as excpected

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, mirror, axis, mirror-modifier

I would like to make a two wires wound on themselves like for light garland (like a spiral).

- To make it easier i use a curve (i will later add bevel and array modifier).
- But I have a problem with mirror modifier, this modifier is very useful to create directly the second wire.

This is the expected result :

[image]

I only succeeded to make the wire mirror around the plan y=0 and not the axis y. I got :
[image]

I have also tried to mirror around a straight curve.

Answer (score 2):

Once twisted, the wires are not reflections of one another in one plane; they both wind in the same direction. If Z is along the helix, wire A is a rotation through 180 of wire B around Z, or A is B scaled by -1 in X and Y, (a reflection in 2 planes simultaneously, which the *Mirror* modifier doesn't do).

**TLDR**; You can mirror the wires *before* twisting:

[image]

Foreground, front to back, with the following modifiers:

- A straight Bezier curve, subdivided into a reasonable number of 'Automatic' control points, and offset in X from its object origin, in Edit Mode.
- *Mirror*ed in X
- *Simple Deform > Twisted* through 360, around Z
- *Array*ed in Z

Background: *Curve*d  around another spiral curve.

If you need two colors in the flex, you can offset the V of the UV by -1 in the *Mirror* modifier's 'Data' section, and use nodes something like this..

[image]

..testing for V < 0.

Comment: To make a straight Bezier, call up the default curve, and hit 'VV' in Edit Mode.